# How can I set a css border on one side only?

Tags: css, border

For a given `div` I would like to only display a border on the left, right, top, or bottom side.

Currently I have the following, which puts a border on all sides:

```
#testdiv {
   border: 1px solid;
}
```

What do I need to do in order to have a **border only on the left side**?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

```
#testdiv {
   border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

See [the MDN documentation on border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border).

Answer (score 35):

If you want to set 4 sides separately use:

```
border-width: 1px 2em 5px 0; /* top right bottom left */
border-style: solid dotted inset double;
border-color: #f00 #0f0 #00f #ff0;
```

Answer (score 24):

```
    div{
    border-left:solid red 3px;
    border-right:solid violet 4px;
    border-top:solid blue 4px;
    border-bottom:solid green 4px;
    background:grey;
    width:100px; height:50px
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SdB62/4/)

Answer (score 15):

You can specify border separately for all borders, for example:

```
#testdiv{
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #FF0;
}
```

You can also specify the look of the border, and use separate style for the top, right, bottom and left borders. for example:

```
#testdiv{
  border: 1px #000;
  border-style: none solid none solid;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try like this

```
#testdiv{
  border-left:1px solid;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

```
#testDiv{
    /* set green border independently on each side */
    border-left: solid green 2px;
    border-right: solid green 2px;
    border-bottom: solid green 2px;
    border-top: solid green 2px;
}
```