# how to make this shape for title?

Tags: html, css

I would like to make this shape for the title.

[image]

What HTML and CSS should I use to make this shape?

Comment: try borders left and right. Also a search would have given you an answer. Also show a little effort is what you have done so someone can help you solve the issues in your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set a css border on one side only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405307/how-can-i-set-a-css-border-on-one-side-only)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `border` property (`border-left` & `border-bottom`), like:

```css
.title {
  border-left: 5px solid #444;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  padding-left: 15px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">This is a title</h1>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its my pleasure @KatePark

Answer (score 0):

For creating a shape like you asked for, you can use any html tag (in my case I used h1 tag).
I've given my tag a class `.title`, you can give any. To this class I've only assigned basic and required properties to achieve what you asked for, you can give any set of properties as you desire together with these.
Below I'm attaching a snippet please go through.

```css
.title {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #ababab;
  border-left-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">This is my title</h1>
```

Comment: @SauravRastogi, I didn't see your post earlier, as I was writing mine. Talking about the difference there isn't much it's just way of using properties. You used `border-left` and `border-bottom` separately and I used `border-width`, `border-style` and `border-color` to achieve the same.